# Accessing Noder functionality through C API of GEOS?

Tags: geos

All this stuff looks rather useful:
http://geos.osgeo.org/doxygen/classgeos_1_1noding_1_1Noder.html

However, from the GEOS README file:

`The C++ interface should not be used directly; the geos project
views it as a bug for another program to use the C++ interface or even
to directly link against the C++ library.`

Is there a C interface to the Noding functionality that I'm missing?  I can't find it in `geos_c.h`.

Comment: From Shapely (GEOS port) I don't know how to access Noder functionality too. The solution may be related.

Comment: I have found out that if you union or intersect a line geometry with itself, it comes back noded.  But without any control over the noding algorithm.

Comment: It isn't what I´ve expected, but works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, GEOS C API does not provide access to the Noder features.

> The C++ interface should not be used directly; the geos project views
>   it as a bug for another program to use the C++ interface or even to
>   directly link against the C++ library.

This warning is mainly for those users who rely on GEOS from packaged binaries.
This warning is to help avoid problems like those recently encountered by OSM projects, see [osm2pgsql](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/634) and [libosmium](https://github.com/osmcode/libosmium/issues/168).
Please, read also through the geos-devel list thread [status of C++ API - is it a bug to use it or not?](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/geos-devel/2017-January/007652.html).

However, if you are control build process of your software and instead of relying on packages with GEOS binaries (eg. from your Linux distribution packages), and you can build GEOS yourself, then you will be fine.

Typically, breaking changes in C++ API are not very extensive, so it should not be a huge task or hassle to update your own source to adjust to the changes.

I have used GEOS C++ API in such way for decade, in large projects too.